# How to stop a component being destroyed/unmounted using hooks?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to stop a component being removed from DOM using `useEffect` hook based on certain condition

```
useEffect(() => {
   return () => {
      // prevent component destruction over here .........

     // return false -> not working
    }
}, [])
```

Does React have any event/hook or any trick by which I can control and decide whether a component should get destroyed/unmounted?

Comment: What are your reasons for wanting this?

Comment: `I am trying to stop a component being removed from DOM` ok if you need to keep this component on DOM, refactor your solution to avoid this unmounting. Too naive as comment?

Comment: @FelixKling let us say I have a form on one tab where user has edited something and I want to display a confirmation popup (save/discard changes) if user navigates away from this may be because of some accidental click, route change, by clicking on adjacent tab etc.